# Pinging server replies back with incorrect IP address

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2

I hope this is the correct forum for this posting.

Here's my environment (well, my clients environment):

Gateway: 10.0.0.1 (our router) AD & DNS Server: 10.0.0.8 (Windows 2008 R2) (host name: mainserver) A server running some insurance software (client/server stuff): 10.0.0.47 (Windows Server 2012) (hostname: insserver) An A Record on my DNS Server for "www" is 68.44.122.15 (which points to the company's only website) (not the same IP, I changed it around a little bit).

Client machine: Windows 7 Everything is DHCP for the client.

This doesn't happen to all users, but so far, I've narrowed it down to a single user, but when they use their insurance software and start it up, it'll fail and give crazy error msgs. The user will call me.

First thing I do on their machine: ping insserver. I would expect to see a reply of 10.0.0.47 (since my DNS says insserver is 10.0.0.47). However, I get a reply of 68.44.122.15 (the www in my DNS).

I'll do ipconfig /flushdns, then re-ping the insserver again, and this time, I'll get the correct IP of 10.0.0.47. And now the user can log into the insurance software and do their work. This might last 3-5 days, but eventually the user will call back with the same problem, and I'll repeat the troubleshooting. I'll get the www IP address, flush out the DNS, get the correct IP and everything is back to normal. I can go on anyone elses workstation and ping the insserver and I'll always get the correct IP address in my reply (10.0.0.47).

Why on earth is this happening? And not happening for all the other users, but this only user? Her machine is identical to everyone else. Same OS, same hardware specs, same NIC settings, same everything. Just different users using the computer. For one, I can't understand that part. Second, I can't understand why her computer keeps picking up the www IP address when I ping the insserver. Rather strange.

Anything I should be looking at in more detail on the workstation? My DNS on my server?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: Why are you using ping to diagnose DNS issues?

Comment: I'm just using ping to get a quick and simple reply of what's the IP address of this or that machine.  I know the machine is alive though.  Just need a quick IP rely while on the user workstation. what would you suggest for a DNS issue?

Comment: Have you got the same internal and public domain name?

Comment: You can use nslookup with a DNS server specified to see what each DNS server the computer is configured to use is replying with, also you should check and see if the DNS servers themselves are configured to only send that one IP address. Does the user ever connect from outside the internal network, where the computer could pick up an external IP address for the domain? Can you add rules to let internal traffic going to the external IP work the same way internal to internal works? We had to add rules like this to our network so that mobile users wouldn't have bad records when coming home.

Comment: "Eventually" the user will call back with the same problem. When the problem reappeared, did it happen in the morning as the user starts his workday, or any time of the day?

Comment: @BlueCompute - Yes.  Our website name ...www.whatever.com is the same as our domain name:  whatever.com  (previous IT person made this up...).

Comment: Workaround: Put an entry in the users hosts file. But before anyone moans about figuring out why its happening.... yes, you should figure out why its happening :D

Comment: Are you pinging insserver or insserver.domain.com?  Either way it seems you have broken split-brain DNS.  Last Q, is this a laptop that goes off the network?

Comment: @BlueCompute - Not a laptop.  It's a virtual machine that never leaves the network.  I'll had an entry into the host file.  If this is just a band-aid and works, then that'll work for me.  This user is the only person w/this issue (which doesn't help me much, because all users have the same network settings on their computers).

Comment: Thanks everyone for replying.  I resolved the issue by adding an entry into the HOST file and removing a DNS entry.

For some strange reason, there was an A Record for WWW on my DNS server that pointed to the external IP address of the company's website.  Not sure why that was there, but no needed.  I removed that entry and no users have received errors or at least when I ping the server and do nslookup, I'm getting the correct IP address.